# How to upload a SSL certificate to IAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am following [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_server-certs.html) and want to upload my SSL Certificate to IAM (on AWS).

The guide says:

> To use the following example command, replace these file names with
>   your own and replace ExampleCertificate with a name for your uploaded
>   certificate. Type the command on one continuous line. The following
>   example includes line breaks and extra spaces to make it easier to
>   read.
>
> ```
> $ aws iam upload-server-certificate 
>                         --server-certificate-name ExampleCertificate
>                         --certificate-body file://Certificate.pem
>                         --certificate-chain file://CertificateChain.pem
>                         --private-key file://PrivateKey.pem
> ```

I am new to AWS and don't understand what should I do here?

- I don't know on which command line / console should I execute the above command?
- I have 2 files from GoDaddy (`some_hex_chars.crt` and `gd-g2_iis_intermediates.p7b`) how should I put these 2 files in the above command?

Comment: You have to install AWS CLI first. Then run that command,

Comment: @Akshaybarahate: thanks, I have installed AWS CLI Command... I still don't know how to get cert body, chain and private key out of those 2 files though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**AWS** :The certificate, private key, and certificate chain must all be PEM-encoded.

> I have 2 files from GoDaddy (some_hex_chars.crt and
>   gd-g2_iis_intermediates.p7b) how should I put these 2 files in the
>   above command?

**some_hex_chars.crt** = Certificate body

**gd-g2_iis_intermediates.p7b** = Certificate chain

**The private key** you created in the beginning along with your CSR may not be in PEM format.

**For PEM format preparation you need OpenSSL**

**Private Key :** Use the command below to create a private key in PEM format.

```
openssl rsa -in server.key -outform PEM > server.private.pem
```

**Certificate Chain**

```
openssl pkcs7 -in gd-g2_iis_intermediates.p7b -print_certs -out CertificateBundle.pem
```

**Certificate body**

```
openssl x509 -in some_hex_chars.crt -out mycert.pem -outform PEM
```

**OR**

```
openssl x509 -inform DER -in some_hex_chars.crt -out outcert.pem -text
```

Once you have required format run you command

```
$ aws iam upload-server-certificate 
                        --server-certificate-name ExampleCertificate
                        --certificate-body file://Certificate.pem
                        --certificate-chain file://CertificateChain.pem
                        --private-key file://PrivateKey.pem
```

Let me know if this works for you.